# error Cannot find Python Imaging Library (PIL or Pillow)

Tags: ubuntu, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am trying to run a Python script from this website:  http://code.behnam.es/python-lfp-reader/

In the terminal on Ubuntu, on a Python command line I run the following:

```
lfp-picture.py export IMG_0002-stk.lfp
```

at first the script processes the images through image 10, then creates a.raw file and a .txt file, thend I get the error message:

> lfp-picture.py: error Cannot find Python Imaging Library (PIL or Pillow)

I have everything installed, including Python Imaging Library, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling via the Ubuntu Software Center, but I still get the error message.

Comment: How did you install PIL? What does the output of `python -c "import PIL; print PIL"` look like?

Comment: <module 'PIL' from 'usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.pyc'>

Comment: The setup.py for lfp-reader says that it's looking for Pillow. Maybe lfp-reader is looking for the Python Imaging Library in the wrong location?  Or, maybe a different version?

Comment: Try adding the `--debug` flag to the script, and paste the entire output of your session in your question. Don't summarize. We want the whole thing.

Comment: I will paste the output from debug as soon as I have get to the Ubuntu machine, about 8 hours from now. Thanks!  I didn't of that, I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: what is the syntax for the debug flag?  Is it like:
lfp-picture.py export IMG_0002-stk.lfp --debug    

do I need to install pdb?

Comment: in the lfp-picture.py script it has DEBUG = False  and   QUIET = False,  I assume if I change those to True, that will output useful debugging info?

Comment: 1$ lfp-picture.py export IMG_0002-stk.lfp --debug
LFP Picture file: IMG_0002-stk.lfp
Create file: IMG_0002-stk__refocus_00.jpeg
Create file: IMG_0002-stk__refocus_01.jpeg
Create file: IMG_0002-stk__refocus_10.jpeg
Create file: IMG_0002-stk__depth_lut.raw
Create file: IMG_0002-stk__depth_lut.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/lfp-picture.py", line 122, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/lfp-picture.py", line 117, in main
    args.subcmd(**dict(args._get_kwargs()))
  File "/usr/local/bin/lfp-picture.py", line 60, in export

Comment: File "/usr/local/bin/lfp-picture.py", line 60, in export
LfpPictureFile(lfp_file).load().export()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lfp_reader/lfp_picture.py", line 260, in export 
self.export_all_focused()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lfp_reader/lfp_picture.py", line 290, in export_all_focused
pil_all_focused_image = self.get_pil_image('all_focused')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lfp_reader/lfp_picture.py", line 368, in get_pil_image
check_pil_module()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lfp_reader/_utils.py", line 66, in check_pil_module

Comment: File "/usr/local/bin/lfp-picture.py", line 60, in export
LfpPictureFile(lfp_file).load().export()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lfp_reader/lfp_picture.py", line 260, in export
self.export_all_focused()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lfp_reader/lfp_picture.py", line 290, in export_all_focused
pil_all_focused_image = self.get_pil_image('all_focused')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lfp_reader    raise RuntimeError("Cannot find Python Imaging Library (PIL or Pillow)")
RuntimeError: Cannot find Python Imaging Library (PIL or Pillow)

Comment: I had to put the debug info in three separate comments because it was longer than the allowed character limit for comments.